# Not enough Results in Custom Search Engine (Google search API)

Tags: search, google-programmable-search-engine, google-search-api

I have a really big problem:

- I'm using the Google Custom Search Engine `CSE` with the REST API to find some URL but a lot of search engine results are missing.
- I look on the internet about this fact and a lot of people have the same problem. e.g

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173457/why-google-web-search-api-custom-search-engine-and-page-search-results-are-diff
- If I used the keyword "site:" to see how many page are indexed in `CSE` I found a few result but in a normal web browser I found about 93% more results.
- Here is the test for "site:stackoverflow.com"

  ```
  Web : 43 400 000 results
  CSE : 3 190 000
  ```

Anyone has experienced the same ?

Comment: For the record, any 'site:' search will give you the page index count less (minus/without) the pages that do not pass the various SERP result filters. In other words, it is a count of indexed pages that DO pass the filters. The index count found in Search Console will roughly match the 'site:' search when no pages are filtered. Otherwise, you cannot count on this metric.

Answer (score 1):

Google's `site:` search result count is a very inaccurate measure.  See:

- [Why Google Can’t Count Results Properly](http://searchengineland.com/why-google-cant-count-results-properly-53559)
- [Is Google search site:yoursite.com result count a good indicator of Google's indexing and does it really mean anything in SEO terms?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49658/is-google-search-siteyoursite-com-result-count-a-good-indicator-of-googles-ind)

The bottom line is that you can use Google's estimates of the number of results to figure out how many documents are indexed.   There may be far more, or far fewer documents in the index compared to the number Google prints for the result count.  The *only* way that Google for you to estimate the number of pages indexed for a particular site is to see the number for your verified site in Google Search Console.

Unless you have found a specific document that is in the search results for the `site:` search, but doesn't come up in the CSE, you don't have a problem.

Comment: The problem is not the number ! I'm looking for content that is never indexed in the CSE but in normal search with a web browser.

Comment: If you have an example of such content, add it to your question.   There likely won't be any if you are just going based on the fact that the search result counts don't match.

Comment: For confidentiality reasons I can't give you the website but whatever, we will call it the "x-website.com". So in this case, using the keyword "site:x-website.con" to know how many pages are indexed :

- Normal Search with web browser : 1 180 pages indexed
- CSE : 0 pages indexed

If CSE and Normal Websearch have differents results I can't use this API for my project... Do you understand more with this example ?

Comment: If the CSE doesn't have any results, there must be a problem with how you set it up, no?

Comment: No. I have results for bigger websites like stackoverflow like in my test shown above. I think the CSE is just a sample of the real Google Search Engine. If you look on the internet, every people have the same problem as me.

Comment: Your result for StackOverflow in not conclusive because it is based on search result count estimates.   You'd need to find a better example for me.  I have CSE set up for my site: [potato](http://savvyroo.com/search?cx=partner-pub-4597759259828304%3A2519469479&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=potato&ga.x=0&ga.y=0) vs site search [potato](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&q=site%3Asavvyroo.com+potato)  -- both have three results.    If I search for something more common such as the brand name I get differing result count estimates, but those are just that, estimates.